# $yz_x=z(x,y)$ for $x=2$ and $z=y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$yz_x=z(x,y)\text{ for }x=2\text{ and }z=y$$

$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{dy}{0}$$

$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{0}$$

$$0=y\,dy$$

$$\frac{y^2}{2}=C_1$$

$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}$$

Because $y$ is a constant we can integrate straight away

$$\frac{x}{y} = \ln\left|C_2 \cdot z\right|$$

$$\frac{e^{\frac{x}{y}}}{z}=C_2$$

But what now? I somehow need to find $z = \cdots$ as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found $0=ydy$ thus $dy=0$
$$y=C_1$$
Also you found $$\frac{e^{x/y}}{z}=C_2$$
You want to use the Charpit-Lagrange method. For that you need to learn this method and understand that the solution is given by the implicit equation $F(C_1,C_2)=0$ :
$$F(y\:,\:\frac{e^{x/y}}{z})=0$$
with $F$ an arbitrary function of two variables.
Or equivalently on explicit form $C_2=f(C_1)$
$$\frac{e^{x/y}}{z}=f(y)$$
with $f$ an arbitrary function.

Condition : $y=z$ for $x=2\quad\implies\quad \frac{e^{2/y}}{y}=f(y)$

Now the function $f(y)$ is known. We put this function in the above general solution 
$$\frac{e^{x/y}}{z}=\frac{e^{2/y}}{y}$$
$$z=ye^{x/y}e^{-2/y}=ye^{(x-2)/y}$$

Answer (score 0):

A different approach

$$
y z_x = z\Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ln z = \frac 1y\Rightarrow \ln z = \frac xy + \Phi(y)\Rightarrow z = e^{\frac xy}\Psi(y)
$$

now considering the boundary conditions

$$
y = e^{\frac xy}\Psi(y)\Rightarrow \Psi(y) = y e^{-\frac 2y}
$$

and finally

$$
z = e^{\frac xy}y e^{-\frac 2y} = y e^{\frac{x-2}{y}}
$$

Comment: But you know, I can't afford to learn different approaches right now. Our teacher wants us to calculate after his scheme. Regarding the calculations I've made, what would be the way to come to the solution?